# How to create checkbox for single item in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I know to create a multiple checkbox in the form if I have list of items.

**forms.py**

```
class GatewayForm(forms.Form):

GATEWAY_CHOICES = (

        ('Instamojo', 'Instamojo'),
        ('CCAvenue', 'CCAvenue'),
        ('ePaisa', 'ePaisa'))
gateway_name = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=GATEWAY_CHOICES)
```

**template.html**

I use a for loop to display the gateway_names.

---

Now how can I achieve the same when there is only one item in the list?

```
GATEWAY_CHOICES = (

        ('Instamojo', 'Instamojo'),
```

What form field or widget should I use?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add "required = False,"

```
gateway_name = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required = False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=GATEWAY_CHOICES
)
```

I hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BooleanField` type of field and set its `required` attribute to `False`

```
instamojo=forms.BooleanField(label='Instamojo',required=False)
```

This will create a check box like field that can either be checked or unchecked.

Comment: when a post request is made I get a Boolean value (True or False), I want the value to be Instamojo and not true or false, how can I achieve that?